# How do we initialize a std::byte with a double?

Tags: c++, c++17, byte, std-byte

I'm attempting to use `std::byte` for the first time but I'm failing to initialize the value.

```
#include <cstddef>

double red_double = 0.5;
auto red_byte = std::byte(red_double * 255);
```

Results in: `error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'double' to 'std::byte'`

This seems like a mind-numbingly simple task but I guess std::byte works differently to normal types. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm compiling with MSVC 19.22 which apparently claims to fully support std::byte:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019

Comment: a floating point into a byte???

Comment: yes? narrowing of types is a standard feature of c++

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile the code with clang 8.0 and gcc 9.2, but the code failed to compile with msvc 19.22 compiler. Hence there is no full support for std::byte with msvc compiler as of now.

By the way there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Interestingly, MSVC claim it is supported
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019